# Import issue in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have the following import in my java code in an eclipse project

```
import org.jscience.*;
```

However upon writing the code

```
Real r1 = new Real.valueOf(1);
```

I receive the error

```
Real cannot be resolved to a type
```

I am puzzled as to why this is happening as I am correctly importing (or so I believe)

Also to note, eclipse suggests using

```
import org.jscience.mathematics.number.Real;
```

But I am trying to avoid using the import for the full class location within the Jar.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: Try using `import org.jscience.Real;` I think you wouldn't be able to do this.. Probably because `Real` is not directly inside `org.jscience`.. That is why eclipse asked to use that other package..

Comment: try `import org.jscience.mathematics.number.*;`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: I understand why it wasn't working now after Rohit Jains comment since the Real is not directly inside org.jscience :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
import org.jscience.mathematics.number.*;
```

Because

```
import org.jscience.*;
```

will actually only import classes from within the `jscience` package and not any subpackages.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose your import is not throwing errors, try importing `g.jscience.mathematics.number.*`.

Comment: Thats works, thanks! I understand why it wasn't working now after Rohit Jains comment since the Real is not directly inside org.jscience :D